# Writing data into a VB(Variable Block) file using FTP/FTPS

Tags: java, ftp, mainframe

```
package base;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient;
import com.ibm.jzos.ZFile;

public class FTPSVB {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedInputStream binp=null;
    BufferedOutputStream bout=null;

    String server, username, password, fileTgt, fileSrc;
    String protocol = "TLS";    // SSL/TLS
    FTPSClient ftps = new FTPSClient(protocol);
    FTPSClient ftps2 = new FTPSClient(protocol);
    server="***";
    username="***";
    password="***";
    fileSrc="ABC00T.SMP.SAVE.ULRL";
    fileTgt="ABC00T.SMP.SAVE.OUT.ULRL";
    try
    {
        int reply;
        ftps.connect(server);
        ftps2.connect(server);
        reply = ftps.getReplyCode();
        reply = ftps2.getReplyCode();
    }
    try
    {
        ftps.setBufferSize(200);
        ftps.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); 
        if (!ftps.login(username, password))
        {
            ftps.logout();
            System.out.println("ERROR..");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        ftps.execPBSZ(0);
        ftps.execPROT("P");

        ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftps.setAutodetectUTF8(true);
        ftps.site("QUOTE RDW");
        ftps2.setBufferSize(200);
        ftps2.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);    
        ftps2.site("QUOTE RDW");
        ftps2.site("QUOTE recfm=VB lrecl=106 blksize=27998");
        if (!ftps2.login(username, password))
        {
            ftps2.logout();
            System.out.println("ERROR..");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        ftps2.execPBSZ(0);
        ftps2.execPROT("P");
        ftps2.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftps2.setAutodetectUTF8(true);
        binp=new BufferedInputStream(ftps.retrieveFileStream(fileSrc));
        bout=new BufferedOutputStream(ftps2.storeFileStream(fileTgt));
        final byte []bufLen= new byte[4];
        int readLen=binp.read(bufLen, 0, 4);// Read len
        int recCounter=1;
        while(readLen!=-1){
        ByteArrayInputStream ba2=new ByteArrayInputStream (bufLen,0,4);
            int z=ba2.read();
            int reclen=0;
            int li=0;
            while(z!=-1){
                if(li==0)
                    reclen+=z*256;
                else if(li==1)
                    reclen+=z;
                li++;
                z=ba2.read();
            }
            ba2.close();
            reclen-=4;
            byte []buf=new byte[reclen];
            readLen=binp.read(buf, 0, reclen);
            boolean isEOF=false;
            while(readLen<reclen) {
                int nextLen=binp.read(buf, readLen, reclen-readLen);
                if(nextLen==-1){// End of file is reached.
                    isEOF=true;
                    break;
                }
                readLen=readLen+nextLen;
            }
            String a=new String(buf, ZFile.DEFAULT_EBCDIC_CODE_PAGE);
            StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder(a);
            //str.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            System.out.println(""+str);
      //appending extra space for record till its length matches file record length
           if(str.length()<102) {
                for (int i = str.length(); i < 102; i++) {
                    str.append(" ");
                }
            }
            byte []outBytes=new byte[102];
        outBytes=str.toString().getBytes(ZFile.DEFAULT_EBCDIC_CODE_PAGE);
            bout.write(outBytes);
            if(isEOF){
                break;
            }
            readLen=binp.read(bufLen, 0, 4);// Read length- RDW 
            recCounter++;
        }
        bout.flush();
        bout.close();
        binp.close();
        ftps.completePendingCommand();
        ftps2.completePendingCommand();
        ftps.logout();
    }
    catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Server closed connection.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (ftps.isConnected())
        {
            try
            {
                ftps.disconnect();
            }
            catch (IOException f)
            {
                // do nothing
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    }
 }
```

I am using the above code to read and write a VB file. I am able to read the variable block records. but while writing if I dont append the extra space to match the file record length, the data is getting jumbled. If I add extra space to it, it consumes a lot of memory. Am I missing something here? How can I solve this issue?..

Comment: Small thing...I notice for ftps2, you are sending the "SITE QUOTE" commands prior to logon - I think you may need to login first, then send your SITE commands. From your description, it also sounds like you're not really getting VB format records...if you have a way to logon to the mainframe with TSO, check the file attributes to make sure FTP allocated the VB dataset you think it should have. I always like to try these things in an interactive session by hand until I'm sure everything is working as expected before writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is with `ftps2.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`.

Windows/Unix/Linux files don't know anything about "records", every file is just a stream of bytes. When working with text files that stream may contain end-of-line-characters (`x0A`,`x0D` or `x0D0A` in ASCII). These may be interpreted as end of a record and start of a new one, so most FTP-tools would start a new record on the z/OS side when they encounter one of these *in text mode* (and vice versa add one when starting a new record when transfering *from* z/OS).

With binary files things are a bit different, since `x0D` and `x0A` are not treated in any special way but are just two byte values among others.

So to get what you want you have these posibilities:

1. Transfer the file using text-mode, but this will likely result in some sort of codepage-conversion being done. If possible you might configure a custom translation-table doing no conversion at all.
2. Transfer the file in binary to some FB dataset and write a tool to split the continuous bytestream at the correct line-termination character and write the resulting records to a VB-dataset.